# When exactly can I revive people in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

When I take the Assault class, I'd like to work as a diligent reviver. But in many cases (about 60% subjectively), although I can see the heartbeat symbol over the lying team mate, I cannot revive him: Nothing happens when I apply the paddles. 
And a couple of seconds later he indeed taps out.

This has been breaking my heart and haunting my dreams.

So please help me, my fellow doctors: Is there some mechanism I don't know behind this, like a time to precharge or something like that?

Comment: Afaik there isn't a certain to do this. I've not had problems like this, but I have had people where the skull or heartbeat symbol dissapears but I can still revive them (if it's done right after).

Plus when getting revived yourself, you often have to press Space to stand up, otherwise you're just prone with your pistol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure you use the defibrillator on their torso. If it fails, try again, if it fails for a second time, try going prone.

Keep in mind there are certain times where it might bug out and treat your team mate's body like it's in another location, for example, when someone dies on stairs, and their body rolls to the bottom, every now and then, the game still acts like their body is where they died.

Comment: Interesting. Test this, I will.

Comment: Another thing to note is that there doesn't need to be a heartbeat icon over them, a skull icon can also be revived. I think it's just a graphical glitch that causes them to be skulls sometimes.

Comment: That must be a bug, then

Comment: Agree with Mr Smooth. You have a short window of time to revive your teammate. I myself can recommend proning no matter what.

Answer (score -2):

It could be just lag: by the time you got to him, the player has already respawned.